# Prevent Window Centering in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, window, centering

When I set the position of my game window using `form.DesktopLocation(new Point(X, Y);`, it works, but then XNA automatically resets it to the center of the screen. I tried googling and looking on stack overflow, but I can't seem to figure out how to prevent it centering. Any ideas?

Here's my code manipulating the GraphicsDevice, GraphicsDeviceManager, and the Form controlling the game:

```
// in the initialiser
window = (Form)Form.FromHandle(Window.Handle);
GraphicsDeviceManager = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);

// in the draw method
g.PreferredBackBufferWidth = Width;
g.PreferredBackBufferHeight = Height;
g.ApplyChanges();
f.DesktopLocation = new System.Drawing.Point(X, Y);
```

And that's literally everything. I tried setting the desktop location more than once each frame, before and after the `g.ApplyChanges()`, and that doesn't change anything.

However, just now, I tried removing the `g.ApplyChanges()` and it doesn't do it anymore. Odd. Why would running a `g.ApplyChanges()` before changing the form only sometimes recenter the form AFTER I positioned the form?

Comment: Can you clarify the situation? If it works, when does it get repositioned by XNA exactly?

Comment: At the beginning of the next update, it looks like.

Comment: I tried setting the position over again every frame, but XNA still takes control over the window position, because on the frames that it doesn't call the draw event it still updates it to the center itself.

Comment: It shouldn't do that, can you post your update method?

Comment: I actually don't have anything in my update method, but I'll post what happens in the draw method, give me a couple minutes to edit it into the post.

Comment: Try changing all of your draw method to your "Initialize" method (of the game class), you shouldn't be modifying those values in the Draw method call. Lets see what happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57049/discussion-between-aarilight-and-nahuel-i).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is no solution to this question.**

XNA automatically resets the position of the window to the center of the screen on `g.ApplyChanges`, and whenever it hits another window-related operation, such as resizing, or moving the window from one monitor to another.

**This is a problem in XNA, not with XNA code.** XNA was written with no way to prevent this because their focus is on content, not windows. Therefore, if you want greater control over your forms, it's a better idea to not use XNA at all, or use XNA's output in a form you set up.